# I'm getting "Application did not close the cursor or database object that was opened here" but I put in the command to close it

Tags: android, database, sqlite

here's what's got me stumped. I open the database in the onCreate method
I then call a function to that opens a cursor does a bunch of things, then closes the cursor at the end of the function.

then I put in an OnPause  and I close the database before calling the super.onPause function

I also got an onResume that reopens the database and calls that same function the on create one called to refresh the data.

Finnaly I got a onDestroy function that also closes the database before the super.onDestroy is called.

here's the parts that related to the database
http://pastebin.com/GVcnsVCc

and here's my errors:
http://pastebin.com/Vd6Sdqzp

Also I don't get any errors when I start this activity or while I'm on it, it's when I click on something to go to another activity from this one that I get the errors.

Comment: No need to close it in `onPause` AND `onDestroy` , just onPause would do. Also put a Log message in your `onPause` if statement to see if it is actually closing it

Answer (score 0):

Don't `startManagingCursor(c)`. That's a) deprecated now and b) will try to close() and requery() the cursor for you. That also means that you must not close() the cursor yourself which you can't because you need to close the database as well. (tbh it would work with `stopManagingCursor(c)`)

Since you seem to be handling the query yourself you can simply skip that part.

Also you could directly close the database once you are finished with `getdata()`. There is no need to keep it open unless you constantly read/write data while your app is active.